union of dynamically mapped tasks in airflow
i am implementing an ETL pipeline in Apache AirFlow across different API endpoints:

extract: scrape API endpoint
transform
load

the docs go into how dynamic task mapping to reuse tasks, which in my case helps generalize across endpoints for example.
i would then have tasks return wherever they stored their output, such that the next one can continue where the previous one left off.
in practice there is a bit of branching involved tho (with the scraping of some endpoints depending on the data of others, e.g. /foos/ and /bars/ can come first, but /foos/{id}/bazs/ would come after).
nevertheless tho, i would prefer to instantiate my transform/load steps just once, taking the scraped results as their input, rather than duplicating this over the branching.
this makes me wonder: is there a way to 'union' XComArgs such as to conciliate the results from tasks in such a way?
i imagine one might add a task taking various mapped tasks as inputs and simply returning a sequence of their results. however, it would sound like this would both involve custom implementation, as well as depending on all prior inputs to finish first, disallowing downstream tasks to trigger until that point.
am i simply missing something about how to use AirFlow?
i unfortunately failed to find an existing union-like operation defined on their XComArg class.
edit: filed as a featured request
